# Add arrays that do not have the same length

Tags: arrays, matlab, addition

**Problem**

Is there a smart way to add arrays/vectors that do not have the same column length, by just adding zeros to columns that are too short? I have additions/subtractions that include multiple variables.

so that:

```
a=[ 1; 2; 3]; b=[1;5]
a+b=[2; 5; 3]
```

or:

```
a-b=[0;-3;3]
```

instead of:

> Error using  + 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.

**What I did**

```
 b(numel(a),1) = 0;
```

This works fine, if adding a few variables, but this gets quite annoying while repeating for multiple variables, especially if you don't know which has the longest column. Hence the question if there is an easier fast way for an addition of different column lengths.

**Edit**

The question really is, if there is a way to automate this for having more than "just a few" variables.

Comment: usually, you just create a function say : "MyAdd" and in it write all the processes so you don't have to write it every time....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939711/how-to-add-vectors-with-different-length

Comment: @BlackAdder I am looking for a smart way, not just adding zeros by hand

Comment: why not create a function ?

Comment: Well, you are trying to do an operation that is mathematically incorrect, which Matlab doesn't allow (since Matlab is a software to perform mathematical operations). You can of course increase the dimensionality of a vector so now it refers to a new coordinate system which is "compatible" with the other vector. Once the two vectors are "compatible" you can perform any operation defined under the new coordinate system. It's like adding apples and pears. You cannot do it, unless you convert a pear into an apple. Then when you only have apples you can add them.

Comment: One way would be to save those into a cell array and then use bsxfun's masking capability to create a regular 2D array and then do summation, subtractions, anything, as shown here : [`Adding 0's to cell array  ...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739263/adding-0s-to-cell-array-such-that-each-column-contains-an-equal-number-of-entri).

Comment: Fix the typo you made here: `a+b=[2; 5; 3]`. It should be   `a+b=[2; 7; 3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it more or less manually. For example:

```
s = [];
s(1,1:numel(a)) = a;
s(2,1:numel(b)) = b; % assigning a row (or column) automatically pads with zeros
    % if needed. This works irrespective of which is bigger, a or b
s = sum(s,1); % sum along each column
```

If you have **several variables**, it's probably better to put them in a cell array, so you can loop over them:

```
c = {[1; 2; 3] [1;5] [10 20 30 40]}; % cell array of all "variables"
s = [];
for k = 1:numel(c);
    s(k,1:numel(c{k})) = c{k}; % this zero-pads preceding cells' contents if needed
end
s = sum(s,1); % sum along each column
```

The above may be slow because `s` is dynamically reallocated. You can **preallocate** as follows:

```
c = {[1; 2; 3] [1;5] [10 20 30 40]}; % cell array of all "variables"
m = max(cellfun(@numel, c)); % maximum vector size
s = zeros(numel(c), m); % preallocate and initiallize to zeros
for k = 1:numel(c);
    s(k,1:numel(c{k})) = c{k}; % some entries maybe be left as zero
end
s = sum(s,1); % sum along each column
```

Comment: You should preallocate `s` with the biggest of the two vectors:  `s=zeros(1, max(numel(a),numel(b))` otherwise in your loop you are resizing `s` at each iteration, which should REALLY be avoided

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[ 1; 2; 3]; b=[1;5];
if numel(b)~=numel(a)
    if numel(b)<numel(a) % If b is shorter, extend it
        b = [b; zeros(numel(a)-numel(b),1)];
    else % If a is shorter, extend it
        a = [a; zeros(numel(b)-numel(a),1)];
    end
end
a+b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is really how would i do this for a 100 variables that I want to add, not just two, then the if statements would get a bit big

Comment: @KiW only if those variables are dynamically named (which is a very bad idea) I can think of an automated way of doing that:  saving the desired variables, loading them as struct and finding the maximum length, padding all others to that length. If they are not dynamically named you'll have to hand-add them to the struct anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
A=[1, 2, 3]; B=[1,5];
[A,zeros(1,length(B)-length(A))]+[B,zeros(1,length(A)-length(B))]

ans =

 2     7     3

[A,zeros(1,length(B)-length(A))]-[B,zeros(1,length(A)-length(B))]

ans =

 0    -3     3
```

Stick them in a function and you are done